# Actionscripts 3 Function doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, air, animate-cc

I write some code for getting current date and compare it with a future date for application limitation. I don't know why this function doesn't work.

```
getYYMMDD();

function getYYMMDD(): String {
    var dateObj: Date = new Date();
    var year: String = String(dateObj.getFullYear());
    var month: String = String(dateObj.getMonth() + 1);
    if (month.length == 1) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    var date: String = String(dateObj.getDate());
    if (date.length == 1) {
        date = "0" + date;
    }
    return year.substring(0, 4) + month + date;

    trace(year + ":" + month + ":" + date);
    if (int(year) > 2017 && int(month) > 5 && int(date) > 31) {
        trace("SYSTEM TIME IS OFF.");
    } else {
        trace("SYSTEM TIME IS ON.");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "return" that happens immediately and the rest of your code doesn't run. Put "return..." at the end of your function, not somewhere in the middle as you have done.

Comment: For future reference, saying "this doesn't work" "isn't helpful".  You should explain what you intend to have happen as well as what actually is happening. Because I guarantee that what is happening is precisely what you are telling it to do. Computers don't disobey or go on strike. And we can't read your mind.

Comment: If you are receiving an error, please put the error and it's details into your question, taking note of the line number the error points to.    If you are getting an unexpected behavior, please explain what is or is not happening in contrast to what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**(1)** Since your function returns data of `String` type...

```
function getYYMMDD(): String
```

Make sure that returned data is **also** being received by a String... *ie:* `someString = getYYMMDD();` means `someString` now has returned value from function.

**(2)** You `return` (exit the function) too soon...

Put `return` as last command to allow all other code inside your function to run.

**(3)** You should consider returning a `Boolean` type (true/false)...

```
var can_Start : Boolean = false; //# assume false before checking

can_Start = getYYMMDD(); //# use function to update status to true/false

if (can_Start == true) { run_Program(); }
else { trace("Sorry time has expired"); }

function getYYMMDD(): Boolean 
{
    var dateObj: Date = new Date();
    var year: String = String(dateObj.getFullYear());

    var month: String = String(dateObj.getMonth() + 1);
    if (month.length == 1) { month = "0" + month; }

    var date: String = String(dateObj.getDate());
    if (date.length == 1) { date = "0" + date; }

    trace(year + ":" + month + ":" + date);

    if(int(year) == 2017)
    {   
        if(int(month) >= 05 && int(date) > 31)
        { trace("SYSTEM TIME IS OFF."); can_Start = false; } //# can_Start == false;
        else { trace("SYSTEM TIME IS ON."); can_Start = true; } //# can_Start == true;
    }

    return can_Start;
}
```

Comment: I don't see your return statement?

Comment: Good point. The last IF statement had a `return false;` and a `return true;` for the conditions. I've made it a bit more obvious now and also found a flaw in the logic of Asker's date checking.